# how to add two galleries in one page using lightbox-0.5

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to add two galleries in one page using lightbox-0.5
 my codes are in [the jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9j5x35zp/)

```
<div id="thumbnails">
    <ul class="clearfix">

      <li><a  href="http://thumb9.shutterstock.com/display_pic_with_logo/64681/296369042/stock-photo-common-modern-business-skyscrapers-high-rise-buildings-architecture-raising-to-the-sky-sun-296369042.jpg" title="Travancore Opus Highway Apartments" rel="lightbox"><img src="http://thumb9.shutterstock.com/display_pic_with_logo/64681/296369042/stock-photo-common-modern-business-skyscrapers-high-rise-buildings-architecture-raising-to-the-sky-sun-296369042.jpg" alt="turntable"></a></li>
      <li><a href="http://thumb1.shutterstock.com/display_pic_with_logo/64681/296369060/stock-photo-sun-reflecting-in-a-usual-modern-business-skyscraper-high-rise-building-architecture-raising-to-296369060.jpg" title="Travancore Opus Highway Apartments" rel="lightbox"><img src="http://thumb1.shutterstock.com/display_pic_with_logo/64681/296369060/stock-photo-sun-reflecting-in-a-usual-modern-business-skyscraper-high-rise-building-architecture-raising-to-296369060.jpg" alt="turntable"></a></li>
     </ul>
  </div>
```

Pls help..

Comment: Pls somebody help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to write a two separate `<ul>` elements for that

For example :

```
    <!-- one set of images -->
<ul class="gallery1">
    <li><a href="image2.jpg" rel="lightbox"><img src="thumb2.jpg"></a></li>     
    <li><a href="image3.jpg" rel="lightbox"><img src="thumb3.jpg"></a></li>     
    <li><a href="image4.jpg" rel="lightbox"><img src="thumb4.jpg"></a></li>     
</ul>
<!-- another set of iamges -->
<ul class="gallery2">
    <li><a href="image2.jpg" rel="lightbox"><img src="thumb2.jpg"></a></li>     
    <li><a href="image3.jpg" rel="lightbox"><img src="thumb3.jpg"></a></li>     
    <li><a href="image4.jpg" rel="lightbox"><img src="thumb4.jpg"></a></li>     
</ul>
```

EDIT :

Use below javascript also .

```
$(function() {

        $('.gallery1 a[rel*=lightbox]').lightBox();
        $('.gallery2 a[rel*=lightbox]').lightBox();
    });
```

Comment: But Both gallery's images are visible in the popup of each gallery.

Comment: If I need this gallery inside of two separate div's, is ID that applied for the div create any issues?

Comment: No , As long as you maintain classes properly.

Comment: can I use **id="thumbnails"** twice in the same page?

Comment: No, You cannot use the same `id` twice in the same page. Anyway, Why do you want to use same `id` ?

Comment: I have a plan to create galleries in separate tabs under same page, so issues will be there?

Comment: You can do it without any issue, `id` won't be an issue for it. The only matter is the class where you put in javascript section.

Comment: any solution for it?

Comment: Yes. Add new class when you need to add a new gallery.